# MCP73871 Battery Under Voltage Protection

Tags: voltage, power, microchip, charger, protection

I want to use MCP73871.

Is there a battery under voltage protection in this charger IC?

or may I use a battery protection IC?

---

**Answer for @Bimpelrekkie**

I decide to use my power architecture as below.

[image: Power Block Diagram]

I add DW01A for protection as your advice.

> My system has GE910QUAD gsm modem and ATmega328P MCU. My MCU works with 7.3728 MHz external crystal and 3v3 power supply. A timer is enabled LDO regulator within a time interval (15 min).

I think this architecture is true, what is your comment?

Comment: How should this battery undervoltage protection act? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Huisman If OP means what I think he means: it is circuitry that prevents the battery from overdischarging. When the battery voltage gets below 3 V, the battery is disconnected so that it cannot discharge further. Over discharging can be very bad (wears the cell out) for Lithium based cells.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Though so already, but the requester knows it best :)

Comment: @Huisman yep you are right I mean if my battery is under 2v4 (i use DW01A in most circuits) disconnect the battery from the circuit; and want that my battery is not be overdischarged.

Answer (score 2):

On page one of the datasheet it says:

> The MCP73871 device includes a low battery indicator

There is no mention of **battery protection** anywhere.

**If** your design uses the Low Battery Status Indicator (LBO) signal to shut down the circuits which drain the battery then I do not think you need extra battery protection.

However, it might be complex to **guarantee** that this will work properly under all conditions so it might be a good idea to simply add a battery protection circuit. A circuit based on the ubiquitous [DW01](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/DW01x-DS-17_EN_53550.pdf) comes to mind. If it was my design, I would simply add that battery protection to cover my behind ;-)

Comment: Do note the LBO does not work when charging! It only works when Vbat > Vin. Moreover, not every MCP73871 is equipped with it.

Comment: I add some information for you dude. @Bimpelrekkie